# php executando ao dar F5 mantendo conexão com o banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tenho uma `function` em Javascript que executa um código PHP, neste PHP eu abro conexão com o banco de dados e envio dados caso algumas entradas recebam 1 (aguardando 1 minuto para mudar o estado delas).

Quando eu atualizo a página antes deste 1 minuto, executa o Javascript e PHP novamente, assim criando uma nova conexão com o banco e criando mais de um registro na execução.

O que eu posso fazer? Tenho como parar a execução do código PHP ao atualizar a página? Seria mais fácil terminar as conexões do banco de dados ao executar o PHP?

Comment: Você pode realizar uma validação antes de inserir o novo registro. Verifica se em um determinado tempo tal candidato a insert no banco já esteja presente, caso esteja, simplesmente ignora o novo insert.

Answer (score 2):

É possível bloquear o botão F5, teste esse código:

http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/C85Hs/

isso vai bloquear o botão F5 até que você atualize.